# What is a regular expression that describes whether an integer w is a multiple of 6?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let's say we are looking at the decimal language $L_6$ where $$\Sigma = \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$$  and $L_6$ accepts an integer w if w is a multiple of 6. I'm trying to find the regular expression for this regular language or prove that it is non-regular.

I think that the language is regular since this is an intersection of the regular languages $L_2$ where it accepts an integer w if it's a multiple of 2, and $L_3$ where it accepts an integer w if it's a multiple of 3. Since regular languages are closed under intersections, $L_6$ must also be regular. But I can't seem to find a regular expression to describe this language.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Designing a dfa for the same would be a good place to start

Comment: What's your regular expression for $L_3$?

Comment: @KellyBundy I dont have a regular expression for $L_3$, but I'm pretty sure it's a regular language and thus exists a regular expression for the language.

Comment: @RinkeshP So you suggest I draw out a dfa for the language and use the dfa to deduce a regular expression?

Comment: @Anonymous123 Then why not do that first? And a regex for $L_2$ as well. Likely the regex for $L_6$ will have elements of both of them. At least I'm sure you'll learn something from (building) them that will help you with $L_6$.